# Can anyone tell me why I am getting a SQL*PLUS invalid identifier error?

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlplus

Why do I keep getting this error:

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: "PURCHASE_PRICE": invalid identifier

As you can see purchase_Price is obviously a valid identifier.

```
      //get parameters from the request
   String homeID=request.getParameter("home_ID");
   String modelID=request.getParameter("model_ID");
   String lotSize=request.getParameter("lot_Size");
   String location=request.getParameter("location");
   String purchasePrice=request.getParameter("purchase_Price");
   String streetName=request.getParameter("street_Name");
   String city=request.getParameter("city");
   String state=request.getParameter("state");
   String zipCode=request.getParameter("zip_Code"); 


  preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer (home_ID, model_ID, lot_Size, location, purchase_Price    , street_Name, city, state, zip_Code)"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

   preparedStatement.setInt(1,Integer.valueOf(homeID));
   preparedStatement.setInt(2,Integer.valueOf(modelID));
   preparedStatement.setString(3,lotSize);
   preparedStatement.setString(4,location);
   preparedStatement.setInt(5,Integer.valueOf(purchasePrice));
   preparedStatement.setString(6,streetName);
   preparedStatement.setString(7,city);
   preparedStatement.setString(8,state);
   preparedStatement.setString(9,zipCode);
   preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

SQL CODE

```
   CREATE TABLE home
    (home_ID        NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    model_ID        NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    lot_Size        VARCHAR2(50)        ,
    location        VARCHAR2(50)        ,
    purchase_Price      NUMBER          ,
    street_Name     VARCHAR2(50)        NoT NULL,
    city            VARCHAR2(30)        NOT NULL,
    state           VARCHAR2(50)        NOT NULL,
    zip_Code        VARCHAR(5)      NOT NULL
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because you are showing us a table `home` in the SQL but inserting into `customer` with JDBC?

Comment: Yeah. . . I a just saw that.  I am soooooooo special :/